# SVG elements say on top left corner of container

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

New to SVG. I followed few samples for SVG and I was able to create elements manually. Now I am trying to create SVG elements from a Json file. The elements get created on the page but they don't show up on their corresponding coordinates.

Example below you will see the all rectangles are in the same position while they should be scattered in the page. I can't really see why is not working.

```
var svg = document.getElementById("mySVG"),
    xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

 var c=[];
c.push(["valu1",13,240]);
c.push(["valu10",130,240]);
c.push(["valu2",120,250]);
c.push(["valu3",130,250]);
c.push(["valu4",140,54]);
c.push(["valu5",130,25]);

for(var i in c) {
   var myLoc = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "rect");
   var xPos =   c[i][1],
       yPos = c[i][2],
       id = c[i][0];

//to create a circle, for rectangle use rectangle
myLoc.setAttribute( "id", id);
myLoc.setAttribute( "cx", xPos);
myLoc.setAttribute( "cy",yPos);
myLoc.setAttribute( "height", 10);
myLoc.setAttribute( "width", 10);
myLoc.setAttribute( "stroke", "yellow");
svg.appendChild(myLoc);
}
```

Here is the updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/czcz/b957u4kb/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG rectangles use `x` and `y` not `cx` and `cy`

```
 var svg = document.getElementById("mySVG"),
    xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

 var c=[];
c.push(["valu1",13,240]);
c.push(["valu10",130,240]);
c.push(["valu2",120,250]);
c.push(["valu3",130,250]);
c.push(["valu4",140,54]);
c.push(["valu5",130,25]);

for(var i in c) {
   var myLoc = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "rect");
   var xPos =   c[i][1],
       yPos = c[i][2],
       id = c[i][0];

//to create a circle, for rectangle use rectangle
myLoc.setAttribute( "id", id);
myLoc.setAttribute( "x", xPos);
myLoc.setAttribute( "y",yPos);
myLoc.setAttribute( "height", 10);
myLoc.setAttribute( "width", 10);
myLoc.setAttribute( "stroke", "yellow");
svg.appendChild(myLoc);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b957u4kb/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try It: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/njkq1qs2/2/)

your id is not an var and one more issues rect has `X` and `Y` not `cx` and `cy`

```
myLoc.setAttribute( "id", id);
```

create dynamic id

```
myLoc.setAttribute( "id", "id"+i);//here i is under loop
```